# USI Webservice SOAP Format

Tags: php, web-services, security, soap

I am in the process of developing process to communicate with the Unique Student Identifier (USI) Webservice. I have a Vanguard token, courtesy of some nice (SoapClient avoiding) code by Sergey Vidusov (thanks!) and I'm trying to use the contents of that token in my (also SoapClient avoiding) SOAP request to the USI service. I am using the "example security header" from the V2.0 Technical Services contract (P79) as a template and trying to fill in the blanks from the token and despite a few dozen slightly varied iterations, I constantly get:

`An error occurred when verifying security for the message.`

in the SOAP fault section of the response. I won't be surprised to learn that I am going about this the wrong way, but I am, for the moment out of ideas.

From the token, I am taking the Binary Secret and using it as the Signature value and the `SecurityTokenReference->KeyIdentifier` as the KeyIdentifier in my request. I've also copied the entire `EncryptedAssertion` section from the token in to the request.

My (supposedly valid) XML is like

```
<s:Envelope
xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
<s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://usi.gov.au/ws/2015/VerifyUSI</a:Action>
    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid-594a3e4f2c463</a:MessageID>
    <a:ReplyTo>
        <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>
    </a:ReplyTo>
    <a:To s:mustUnderstand="1"> http://usi.gov.au/ws/2015/VerifyUSI </a:To>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1"
        xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
        <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
            <u:Created>2017-06-21T09:37:19.000Z</u:Created>
            <u:Expires>2017-06-21T10:37:19.000Z</u:Expires>
        </u:Timestamp>
        <EncryptedAssertion
            xmlns="urn:oasinametc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
            <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlnxenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"/>
                <KeyInfo
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <EncryptedKey xmlne="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                        <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p">
                            <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        </EncryptionMethod>
                        <KeyInfo>
                            <SecurityTokenReference xmlno="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                                <X509Data>
                                    <X509IssuerSerial>
                                        <X509IssuerName>CN=Australian Government Notary Services OCA, OU=For Development purposes ONLY, OU=Australian Authentication and Notary Services, O=Australian Government, C=AU</X509IssuerName>
                                        <X509SerialNumber>137894267415199651126496945754681728351</X509SerialNumber>
                                    </X509IssuerSerial>
                                </X509Data>
                            </SecurityTokenReference>
                        </KeyInfo>
                        <CipherData>
                            <CipherValue>Bc30iHzG4b9ypeC0q8+wvCRox6jTplCg4hKMUpNAXhmhzQyCfFgb3ROihGMB6wLb1moTT/+WpxsMljpeBTKu3oYo8anxwQQf6921Sz7lJCGUrWWMg9IZxq9qEfE85DBqo7tuhs7qkpHlgsUEC/D3IMRycze7x2wJphs6AFBtNDZwVogrQNyp76AUVCGqMSy7EA5woNOuPZqYYHWUDU7/Lv9Jzp6ccOwYXpmnwsW7dMecN6sJbZeopCNf9FuVHS0OJi/l7uadi3VDwRJuiPEB09tETvYNZpUDf/BFQPnHyuWfrjj4nRUKEQx9KcE092+z23n2M8PQmuuEAyRAOnWGNg==</CipherValue>
                        </CipherData>
                    </EncryptedKey>
                </KeyInfo>
                <CipherData>
                    <CipherValue>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</CipherValue>
                </CipherData>
            </EncryptedData>
        </EncryptedAssertion>
        <Signature
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo>
                <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></CanonicalizationMethod>
                <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#hmac-sha1"></SignatureMethod>
                <Reference URI="#_0">
                    <Transforms>
                        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"></Transform>
                    </Transforms>
                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"></DigestMethod>
                    <DigestValue>3d5GbpTJJ2uX3t4fJz3oT3TuaUA=</DigestValue>
                </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>3zexIO6yp7PTD1M7H7BD3rURd2Yj35ELKRSSuLqVHso=</SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
                <o:SecurityTokenReference k:TokenType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.1#SAMLV1.1"
                    xmlns:k="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.1.xsd">
                    <o:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.0#SAMLAssertionID">_ef36244c-da95-47ed-9abf-ddce3c85edd1</o:KeyIdentifier>
                </o:SecurityTokenReference>
            </KeyInfo>
        </Signature>
    </o:Security>
</s:Header>
<s:Body>
    <soap:Body
        xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
        <u:VerifyUSI
            xmlns:u="http://usi.gov.au/2015/ws">
            <u:OrgCode>970003</u:OrgCode>
            <u:USI>ABCDEFGHJK</u:USI>
            <u:FirstName>John</u:FirstName>
            <u:FamilyName>Smith</u:FamilyName>
            <u:DateOfBirth>1971-12-01</u:DateOfBirth>
        </u:VerifyUSI>
    </soap:Body>
</s:Body>
```

I feel I am close ... but just need another clue to propel me forward

Comment: How do you sign that document?

Comment: Therein lies my problem, I believe. I am taking the "token" provided by the STS service, which is a SOAP response from the authorising body and trying to plug "pieces" of it (the common elements) in to my request, which I'm starting to realise doesn't constitute "signing" the request. I am just going to have to learn how to do it properly and implement some kind of PHP WS-Security library. All my research thus far in to SOAP security has led to very basic authorisation, whereas this is quite complex. Send credentials to one site, get something back and use that to submit a request to another.

Comment: If you avoid the SoapClient and love it that much, deal with the consequences: Take care of it and encode yourself. All standard docs with that immense amount of text are actually available online, give it a read, write the implementations, study, develop and improve. You may find here and there some code you can copy and paste, but in the end, it's you who needs to write it together if you don't want to build on the existing client.

Comment: will you help me for this issue.I am facing same issue.
please help me if you fixed this issue

Answer (score 0):

I just ran your XML through an online XML validator at http://www.xmlvalidation.com, and it says `XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.`. Looking at your XML (and this might just be a screwed copy paste to SO), it appears you don't have a closing tag for `</s:Envelope>`.

Add that first if it isn't there. If it is, you'll need to look in your PHP error_log and get the real error message and stack trace so you can debug a little further.

Comment: Yeah, just a copy/paste problem (I actually copied it from a validator). There are no errors PHP-wise, to get clues from. I am getting a legitimate SOAP-XML response from the service - it's just a negative one, saying my security details are wrong.